# Javascript for press return when iframe (or page) loaded

Tags: javascript, iframe, onload, loaded

I have a webpage with an iframe; when loaded I want to send a "return key" press.
I read that the onload hook should work. Can anybody see what I am doing wrong? I am unexperienced in JavaScript. I dont want to use JQuery, I think with plain Javascript it should be possible, too.

Here's my code, that does not work.

```js
onload="alert('done!')";
function () {
  alert("trigger.Event("keydown", {keyCode: 13});");
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://URL_of_the_Iframe_server.js">
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can fire an event in plainjs.

```
var event; // The custom event that will be created

if (document.createEvent) {
  event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
  event.initEvent("dataavailable", true, true);
} else {
  event = document.createEventObject();
  event.eventType = "dataavailable";
}

event.eventName = "dataavailable";

if (document.createEvent) {
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
} else {
  element.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
}
```